# How SELECT `e`.* is coming in Query while printing collection filter in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('grisk_college_new_id', array('in' =>$collegeid))
             ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('in' => array(4, 5)))
             ->addAttributeToFilter('physical_verify', array('null' => true), 'left')
             ->addFieldToFilter('assigned_campus_manager',array('like' => '%_/' . $custid . "%"));
```

> SELECT `e`.*, `at_grisk_college_new_id`.`value` AS
>   `grisk_college_new_id`, `at_physical_verify`.`value` AS
>   `physical_verify`, `at_assigned_campus_manager`.`value` AS
>   `assigned_campus_manager` FROM `customer_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN
>   `customer_entity_int` AS `at_grisk_college_new_id` ON
>   (`at_grisk_college_new_id`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
>   (`at_grisk_college_new_id`.`attribute_id` = '275') LEFT JOIN
>   `customer_entity_int` AS `at_physical_verify` ON
>   (`at_physical_verify`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
>   (`at_physical_verify`.`attribute_id` = '209') INNER JOIN
>   `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_assigned_campus_manager` ON
>   (`at_assigned_campus_manager`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
>   (`at_assigned_campus_manager`.`attribute_id` = '183') WHERE
>   (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') AND (at_grisk_college_new_id.value
>   IN('')) AND (`e`.`group_id` IN(4, 5)) AND (at_physical_verify.value IS
>   NULL) AND (at_assigned_campus_manager.value LIKE '%_/%')

How can I make it more efficient ?

Answer (score 0):

Use reset function:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('grisk_college_new_id', array('in' =>$collegeid))
                 ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('in' => array(4, 5)))
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('physical_verify', array('null' => true), 'left')
                 ->addFieldToFilter('assigned_campus_manager',array('like' => '%_/' . $custid . "%"));

    $collection ->getSelect()
     ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
     ->columns('firstname');
```

Comment: why you are using this reset , ? how does it work?

Comment: it will reset all column and just add those column which you require to select from db

Comment: will it reduce loading time ?

Comment: yes it will reduce time